# supermarket checkout with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am new to python programming. I just started learning python. I need some idea/partial code on how to build the following program. Any idea is appreciated. I have to get following output.

```
----- Welcome to my checkout! -----
Please enter the barcode of your item: 123
Milk, 2 Litres - $2.0
Would you like to scan another product? (Y/N) y
Please enter the barcode of your item: 456
Bread - $3.5
Would you like to scan another product? (Y/N) y
Please enter the barcode of your item: 999
This product does not exist in our inventory.
Would you like to scan another product? (Y/N) n
Payment due: $5.5. Please enter an amount to pay: 5
Payment due: $0.5. Please enter an amount to pay: -3
We don't accept negative money!
Payment due: $0.5. Please enter an amount to pay: 2
----- Final Receipt -----
Milk, 2 Litres $2.0
Bread $3.5
Total amount due: $5.5
Amount received: $7.0
Change given: $1.5
Thank you for shopping at mytsore!
(N)ext customer, or (Q)uit? q
```

what I did till now is:

```
items = {'banana': {'price': 4,   'stock': 6, 'code':123 },
         'apple':  {'price': 2,   'stock': 0,'code':1231 },
         'orange': {'price': 1.5, 'stock': 32,'code':1233},
         'pear':   {'price': 3,   'stock': 15,'code':12335},
        }

bar=int(input("enter barcode:"))
sum = 0
price =[]
products =[]
for key in items:
    if items[key]['code'] == int(bar):
        print("item found")
        print (key)
        print ("price: %s" % items[key]['price'])
        print ("stock: %s" % items[key]['stock'])
        print ("Barcode: %s" % items[key]['code'])
        price.append(items[key]['price'])
        products.append(key)

        print(price)
        print(products)
        print("..............................................")
        while True:

            choice = input("scan another item?y/n")
            if choice =='n':
                for cost in price:
                    sum += cost
                    print("Total cost:",sum)
                    print("..............................................")


            if choice =='y':


                bar=int(input("enter barcode:"))


                for key in items:

                    if items[key]['code'] == int(bar):
                        print("item found")
                        print (key)
                        print ("price: %s" % items[key]['price'])
                        print ("stock: %s" % items[key]['stock'])
                        print ("Barcode: %s" % items[key]['code'])
                        price.append(items[key]['price'])
                        products.append(key)
                    #print(price)
```

if user choose 'n' program should stop and generate the bills/receipt with price. Even I press 'n' options I still get message "scan another item?y/n")". How can I structure my code to get below expected output? I want wrap my code inside functions and create instance using OOP concept

Comment: Add a "break" after you print the total cost.

Answer (score 0):

break is missing in if condition :

```
while True:
        choice = input("scan another item?y/n")
        if choice =='n':
            for cost in price:
                sum += cost
                print("Total cost:",sum)
                print("..............................................")
        break
```

Comment: i want to wrap this code inside functions, and create class instances. please help me

Comment: You may read about classes here:
 http://introtopython.org/classes.html

Comment: As per your requirement above it should work , if you are working with classes now , please update your question .

Answer (score 0):

```
items = {'banana':{'price': 4,   'stock': 6, 'code':123 },
         'apple':{'price': 2,   'stock': 0,'code':1231 },
         'orange':{'price': 1.5, 'stock': 32,'code':1233},
         'pear':{'price': 3,   'stock': 15,'code':12335},}

bar=int(input("enter barcode:"))
sum = 0
price =[]
products =[]
for key in items:
    if items[key]['code'] == int(bar):
        print("item found")
        print (key)
        print ("price: %s" % items[key]['price'])
        print ("stock: %s" % items[key]['stock'])
        print ("Barcode: %s" % items[key]['code'])
        price.append(items[key]['price'])
        products.append(key)

        print(price)
        print(products)
        print("..............................................")
        while True:

            choice = input("scan another item?y/n")
            if choice =='y':
                bar=int(input("enter barcode:"))
                for key in items:

                    if items[key]['code'] == int(bar):
                        print("item found")
                        print (key)
                        print ("price: %s" % items[key]['price'])
                        print ("stock: %s" % items[key]['stock'])
                        print ("Barcode: %s" % items[key]['code'])
                        price.append(items[key]['price'])
                        products.append(key)
                        #sum += items[key]['çost']
                    #print(price)
            if choice =='n':
                for cost in price:
                   sum += cost
                   break
                print("Total cost:",sum)
                print("..............................................")
            break
```